# Laravel datetime on user row now updating

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

Im following a tutorial on adding a last visited feature to my app from here

https://medium.com/@grmcameron/implementing-last-visited-last-seen-in-laravel-237dbbed9027

Basically, add a middleware, add it to the $middlewareGroups in Kernel.php, add a datetime column

```
$table->dateTime('last_online')->nullable();
```

The middleware is as follows;

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Closure;

class LastOnline
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->update([
            'last_online' => new \DateTime(),
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

But for some reason, the column doesnt upload on each request.

If i `dd($user)` it returns the correct user, but no update at all and also no errors are generated.

Just nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made `last_online` column fillable in model ?

Comment: @SagarGautam That has fixed it ..... Thank you

Comment: Does it work for you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure last_online is recorded in your model under the fillable section

```
protected $fillable = ['last_online','...','...'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try

```
$user = Auth::user($yourid);
$user->last_online = new \DateTime()
$user->save();
```

Or

```
$user = Auth::user($yourid);
$user->last_online = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that i needed to add last_online to the $fillable array in the User model.

Comment: Then please close the question :D